# Image upload, resize store path in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Anyone know a good PHP tutorial on how to upload an image, resize it to set dimension, then store the image path in MySQL?

Comment: [Uploading Files with AJAX](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function to do this, Very simple and easy to use.
First put this function somewhere you can call it.

```
public function Resize_image($width = 0, $height = 0, $quality = 90, $filename_in = null, $filename_out = null)
{
    $this->Filename = $filename_in;
    $this->Extension = strtolower($this->Get_file_extension($this->Filename));

    $size = getimagesize($this->Filename);
    $ratio = $size[0] / $size[1];
    if ($ratio >= 1){
        $scale = $width / $size[0];
    } else {
        $scale = $height / $size[1];
    }
    // make sure its not smaller to begin with!
    if ($width >= $size[0] && $height >= $size[1]){
        $scale = 1;
    }

    // echo $fileext;
    switch ($this->Extension)
    {
        case "jpg":
            $im_in = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->Filename);
            $im_out = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0] * $scale, $size[1] * $scale);
            imagecopyresampled($im_out, $im_in, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0] * $scale, $size[1] * $scale, $size[0], $size[1]);
            imagejpeg($im_out, $filename_out, $quality);
        break;
        case "gif":
            $im_in = imagecreatefromgif($this->Filename);
            $im_out = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0] * $scale, $size[1] * $scale);
            imagecopyresampled($im_out, $im_in, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0] * $scale, $size[1] * $scale, $size[0], $size[1]);
            imagegif($im_out, $filename_out, $quality);
        break;
        case "png":
            $im_in = imagecreatefrompng($this->Filename);
            $im_out = imagecreatetruecolor($size[0] * $scale, $size[1] * $scale);
            imagealphablending($im_in, true); // setting alpha blending on
            imagesavealpha($im_in, true); // save alphablending setting (important)
            imagecopyresampled($im_out, $im_in, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0] * $scale, $size[1] * $scale, $size[0], $size[1]);
            imagepng($im_out, $filename_out, 9);
        break;
    }
    imagedestroy($im_out);
    imagedestroy($im_in);
}
```

Now you can use this function like so to resize images and copy it to the required directory.

```
Resize_image($width, $height, $quality=90, $filename_in, $filename_out)
Example..
Resize_image(150, 150, 90, "Directory".$image, "Directory".$image_without_extension."_thumb.".$image_ext); //makes file_thumb.ext
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up using a variation of this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at PHP documentation: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), [GD and Image Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Generally, you have to:

1. Upload file (and check whether it's really an uploaded file with `is_uploaded_file`)
2. Detect image type with `getimagesize` and then use appropriate `imagecreatefrom*` function to create image resource (`$img`)
3. Resize image with something like this:

   ```
   $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
   imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagexs($img), imagesy($img));
   ```
4. Save thumbnail:

   ```
   imagejpeg($thumb, 'file.jpg', 85);
   imagedestroy($thumb); // free memory
   imagedestroy($img); // free memory
   ```
5. Save the information you need to your MySQL database